# Facebook Android SDK and sessions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm working with Facebook's android SDK and I have a question.

So.. in the login flow, in the session callback we get the graph user and response and we can extract appropriate data from these fields.

But I want to fetch the user details every time the app is opened.

What is the correct way to achieve this without having the user to log in every time the app needs to fetch user data.

```
    signInWithFacebookButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));

    signInWithFacebookButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session != null && state.isOpened()) {
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (response != null && user != null) {
                            new ParseLoginTask(user).execute();
                        }
                        facebookProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            } else {
                facebookProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Login Updates in new Facebook SDK , So dont use session

Session Removed - AccessToken, LoginManager and CallbackManager classes supercede and replace functionality in the Session class.

Access Tokens - You can load AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken with the SDK from cache or if the app is cold launched from an app bookmark. For instructions, see Facebook Login for Android, Get Current Token.

And use SharedPreferene to save User data .

Reference May Help you:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#reading https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user